# How to show that $H_0(G,I)=I/I^2$?

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

Recently, I've been studying a little group cohomology and in a set of notes, I saw the following fact assumed: $H_0(G,I)=I/I^2$. Here $G$ is a group and $H_0(G,I)$ is the zeroth homology group with respect to the augmentation ideal $I$ which is the kernel of the natural map from $\mathbb Z[G]\rightarrow G$. Why is this true? Can anyone explain in simple terms. I'm a beginner in these concepts. Than you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial $\mathbb ZG$ module is (sort of by definition) the quotient of  $\mathbb ZG$ by the augmentation ideal $I$ which is the kernel of $\mathbb ZG\longrightarrow \mathbb Z$, and because $H_0(G,-)$ is $\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb ZG} -$, this gives

$$H_0(G,I)=  \frac{\mathbb ZG}{I}\otimes I \simeq \frac{I}{I^2}$$

the last being a general isomorphism $\dfrac{A}{I}\otimes_A M\simeq \dfrac{M}{IM}$.